# Is this jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you hover the images, an orange magnifier pops up.

http://disqus.com/features/

Clicking on the images opens a pop up.

Is that a jQuery plugin that does this and the orange magnifier on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the css for that effect here: http://mediacdn.disqus.com/1308880185/css/marketing.css

Search for `#feature-explorer ul li:hover .frame span`

Comment: How were you able to find the css that did this?

Comment: @Sandra - In Firefox I have Firebug installed. Over the orange magnifier I right-clicked and chose "Inspect Element". That opened Firebug and showed the HTML and CSS for the selected element.  As I moved the mouse to make the magnifier appear and disappear I could see the HTML change and the CSS responsible for it - Firebug also showed the name of the CSS file for the styles applied to the element under the mouse.  Once I knew the filename I right-clicked on the page, selected View Source, and clicked on the appropriate CSS file.

Answer (score 5):

No. it's just CSS's property (pseudo-class)  [`:hover`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)

Answer (score 2):

The magnifier is plain css :hover, while the popup is done using [Facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/), which is a jQuery plugin.